# Adding POCO C++ Library Netbeans on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, poco-libraries

I am trying to use POCO C++ Library with Netbeans IDE on Ubuntu Linux 13.04. I have downloaded, build and installed the POCO C++ Library. The library can be found in the directory "/usr/local/include/Poco". I would like to know how to add the POCO C++ Library to the Netbeans IDE and be able to work with it. Please answer with details.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link an external libraries you need in general three things:

1. To add the header files as an include directory `-I` flag
2. To add the library path to your `POCO C++ *.so` files `-L` flag
3. To add the library name to your compiler without the `lib` prefix, for example with poco would be `poco-Foundation` and the name of your file in your system would be `libpoco-Foundation.so`

Now for Netbeans specific

#### For the header files

`File -> Project Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> General -> Include Directories` which is step one

#### For the library directories

`Project -> properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories` which is step two

#### For the library

`Project -> properties -> Linker ->Libraries -> Add option -> Other` is only for the library file, which is step three.

In the case of the Poco Libraries they are usually handled like the Boost Libraries, for example

```
#include "Poco/AutoPtr.h"
```

This means the Include Directory has to be one level up from the `Poco` folder. For example if your Poco folder is on "/usr/local/include/Poco" then you need to add the "/usr/local/include" to your Include Directories (from step one).

As for the `-L/usr/local/include/Poco` This is not how it is done. This path is the path to your specific library, in the case of `poco` there is `Foundation`, `XML`, `Net`, and `Util` along with the test projects. You need to find the files that are named `libPoco-*.so` where "*" means something. This is most likely in your the directory `usr/local/lib` if those files are not there then they are most likely in `usr/local/lib/Poco`

### If there are no files named `libPoco-*.so` you have to build your Poco libraries separately.

Comment: Hello. First of all in the Poco directory which is included in the "/usr/local/include/Poco" there are only .h files. So I did the following steps 1) In the File->Project Properties->Build->C++ Compiler->General-> Include Directories, I added the whole Poco file. I did the same for steps 2 and 3 that you posted. I tried running a simple example and it didn't compile and gave me an error "g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/pocolibrary build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/local/include/Poco /usr/local/include/Poco". Any suggestions

Comment: The -L directory is different from the Include Directory, Please check the last paragraphs from the edit I made. You also lack the -lpoco-foundation flag, in the end the error should look like this `g++ -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L/usr/local/include/Poco -I/usr/local/include -lpoco-foundation`

Comment: I have modified what you have instructed me to do. In File->Project Properties->Build->C++Compiler->General->Include Directories I added "usr/local/include" inside the include file is the POCO file. In Project->Properties->Linker->Additional Library Directories, I added "usr/local/lib" which included the libPoco-*.so files. I wrote a simple program that I have copied from POCO documentation and I compiled it and got that error "/usr/local/include/Poco/Ascii.h:149: undefined reference to Poco::Ascii::CHARACTER_PROPERTIES'". Is it a problem with POCO build or with the Netbeans IDE

Comment: That's good, it is saying that you need to add the `-l` (l in lowercase) flag, which is step 3. Poco ascii is defined in libPoco-Foundation.so, so now all you need to do is go to `Project -> properties -> Linker ->Libraries -> Add option -> Other` and add `-lPoco-Foundation`or if you have another version of `NetBeans` that says **Add Library** there just type `Poco-Foundation`

Comment: I opened Project->Properties->Linker->Libraries->AddLibrary, I opened "usr/local/lib" and I added "libPocoFounation.so". I ran my program, it compiled with no problems. Is this what you meant by the third step? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. That's great news, hope you enjoy the poco libraries.